# Many operations time out and block process in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, block

We have a lot of operations that time out in our site log.

After installing Redgate SQL Monitor on the server, we figured out we have many blocked processes and some times deadlock.

With Redgate we realized problem is for a stored procedure. It's a simple stored procedure and just increase view count of product (simple update)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_IncreaseProductView]
    @PID int 
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.stProduct 
    SET ViewCount = ViewCount + 1 
    WHERE ID = @PID
END
```

When that stored procedure is off, everything is fine but some times block process error is back.

This table(product) hasn't any trigger. but its like heart of system and has 12000 records.

It has 3 indexes, 1 clustered and 2 non-clustered, and many statistics

We don't have any transaction. block process mostly happens in update query.

How can I figure out where the problem is?

Sorry for my bad languages

Thanks

**Edit:**

I think the problem isn't the `SP`, its about update on product table (Its my opinion). Its large table. I still get block process when `SP` is off but less.
We have a lot of select and update on this table.

Also i rewrite the increase view count with `LINQ to SQL`, but still get block process like when `SP` is on.

**Edit 2:**

I set profiler and get all query on product table.
530 select (most with join with another 2 table) and 25 update per minute (on product table only).

For now, `[SP_IncreaseProductView]` is off. Because when its on, we getting block process and operation timed out about every 10 second and web site stopped.

After that (set `SP` to off) block process still exist but roughly 50 per day.

Comment: Does the table have an `INDEX` on the `ID` column?

Comment: You might try [rebuilding the indices](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187874%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), or [updating the statistics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187348.aspx) and see if the problem persists.

Comment: What is the frequency at which the SP is called?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Another possible cause (but I don't know how likely) is due to parameter sniffing. [Here](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options) is an article that lists several ways to circumvent parameter sniffing. For instance, add option `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` to your query, or `WITH RECOMPILE` to your stored procedure, or "hide" your parameters (assigning procedure parameters to local variables, and referencing the variables instead).

Comment: Is this a database for a web application? Can you cache the number of product views in memory in the application and increment there and just update the database table periodically rather than on every view?

Comment: @marc_s Thanks. i will remove all 'SP_' prefix. but problem still exist without 'SP'

Comment: @TT. 'SP' called in every product page (its web application). i think 2-3 per minutes. for now, i'm reading parameter sniffing article. Also i edited my question and add some information. Thanks

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes its web application (ASP.Net Web Form). I can do that, but problem still exist without that 'SP' but less. Thanks

Comment: You mean each row (~product) is updated 2-3x per minute? So in effect 12K X 3 = 36K updates per minute, correct?

Comment: @TT. no, 'SP' called 2-3x per minute. each product page called 'SP' just one.

Comment: A mere 3 updates per minute on a table with very few rows (12K rows is nothing) leading to blocking... that's nearly impossible even in the worst setup possible. I think there is not enough information in your question to allow us to give a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with Ingaz' second solution, but further optimizations or simplification can be performed:

1) **store view count in a product 1:1 table.** This is particularly useful when some queries do not need view count

2) **view count redundancy**
- keep view count in product table and read it from there 
- also define view count in another table (just productid and viewcount columns)
- application can update asynchronously directly in the second table
- a job updates in the product table based on data from the second table

This ensures that locking is affecting product table much less than independent updates.

Comment: its a long time that i post this question and i clean forgot it. we solve this issue. the solution is exactly your first suggestion. so i checked your answer. tanks

Comment: Yes, it is a long time for me either. However, the question is useful for other users as well, so it really does not matter if we forget about it. It is more important to have decent answers.

Comment: you'r right. this problem was a nightmare for me. i think store view count in a product 1:1 table is a best solution for us.

Answer (score 1):

It is expected: I suppose that you have a lot of updates into single small (12K rows) table.

You can:

1. **Work around your problem**

   Put `ROWLOCK` hint in your `UPDATE`

   Change database option to `READ_COMMITED_SNAPSHOT`

   Be warned though: it can create another problems.
2. **More complex recipe to eliminate blocking completely**

   Not for faint of heart.

   Create table dbo.stProduct_Increment.

   Modify your `[SP_IncreaseProductView]` to `INSERT` into increment table.

   Create periodic task that `UPDATE`s your dbo.stProduct and clear increment table.

   Create view that combines stProduct and stProduct_Increment.

   Modify all `SELECT` statements for stProduct to created view.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I'm in home right now, ill check your idea tomorrow. Also i edited my question and add some additional information

Comment: @VBYOFSKI: Also look carefully which resource is blocking: Table Page, Index Page, other

Comment: unfortunately, problem still exist.  its key resource bloking